# ERROR IN Add Annotations to your Project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, annotations, addition

I am trying the solution here by adding support-annotations and putting the following line in the dependencies block of your build.gradle file and adding com.android.application or com.android.library in gradle.

developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html

But the problem symbols, (1000) and (1001), are still red here:

```
TileView tvOne = new TileView(getContext());
tvOne.setClickable(false);
tvOne.setSelected(matchView.isSelected());
// tvOne.setEnabled(false);
tvOne.setTile(matchView.getTile());
tvOne.setId(1000);

TileView tvTwo = new TileView(getContext());
tvTwo.setClickable(false);
tvTwo.setSelected(otherView.isSelected());
// tvTwo.setEnabled(false);
tvTwo.setTile(otherView.getTile());
tvTwo.setId(1001);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that `TileView` is subclass of `android.view.View`.

So, the parameter to method `.setId` should be declared as resource **id**.

eg.

Create a resource file

`src/main/res/values/ids.xml`

With content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="tileViewOne" type="id" />
    <item name="tileViewTwo" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Then you set.

```
tvOne.setId(R.id.tileViewOne);

tvTwo.setId(R.id.tileViewTwo);
```

Comment: 1000 and 1001 marked red

i did that


.




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> <item name="tileViewOne" type="id" />
            <item name="tileViewTwo" type="id" />
</resources>

Comment: You can not pass a number as parameter to method `setId`, it should be a constant defined in resources id, then you should write `setId(R.id.tileViewOne)` instead of `setId(1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

1000 and 1001 marked RED i did that 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> <item name="tileViewOne" type="id" />
            <item name="tileViewTwo" type="id" />
</resources>`

Answer (score 0):

and that

```
TileView tvOne = new TileView(getContext());
            tvOne.setClickable(false);
            tvOne.setSelected(matchView.isSelected());
            // tvOne.setEnabled(false);
            tvOne.setTile(matchView.getTile());
            tvOne.setId(R.id.tileViewOne);


            TileView tvTwo = new TileView(getContext());
            tvTwo.setClickable(false);
            tvTwo.setSelected(otherView.isSelected());
            // tvTwo.setEnabled(false);
            tvTwo.setTile(otherView.getTile());
            tvTwo.setId(R.id.tileViewTwo);
```